# Calculate the amount each person has to pay to another to balance the expenses between friends

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to find a way to calculate in LibreOffice Calc the amount to be payed to balance the expenses between friends.

A toy example is given below. The minus sign indicates that the person has to receive, the + sign indicates that the person has to pay.

| Person A | Person B | Person C | Person D | Person E | Person F | Person G | Person H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +339.85 | -111.76 | +298.28 | -535.20 | +70.34 | -345.93 | +148.39 | +136.03 |

As result, I would like to have a table showing how much each person has to pay and to whom, so that the accounts are balanced with a minimum number of transactions between people.

Perhaps there's a spreadsheet somewhere that's already been produced to do this type of calculation. I browsed the web but I haven't found one. Please send me a link to such a spreadsheet if you know of one, or give me some hints/pointers so that I can build a spreadsheet that allows this calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Let's think logically.

If we select from the entire list the player with the biggest win and the player with the biggest loss and settle only between them, then one of the players will no longer participate in further transactions. Indeed, either the biggest loser will completely repay his debt, or the biggest winner will receive his winnings in full.

Ideally, both of these players will be excluded from further transactions as a result of mutual settlement.

All that remains is to carry out the same operation with the remaining players.

You can try to implement this algorithm using formulas - find the minimum amount and, using MATCH(), look for the player’s index in the list, find the maximum amount, compare these values, and so on. However, there is an easier way. If you sort the list of players in ascending order, the first one will be the biggest loser, and the last one will be the biggest winner.

Unfortunately, the SORT() function has not yet been implemented for Calc.

However, using simple BASIC code, you can sort an array of values using any of [**a variety of sorting algorithms**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=107599).

Since the list of players is not very large, [**Insertion Sort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) will be quite sufficient.
The code for the procedure for sorting a two-dimensional array by the values of the second column could be like this:

```
Sub InsertionSort(A() As Variant)
Dim LB As Long, I As Long, J As Long, aTempName As Variant, aTempValue As Variant
    LB = LBound(A)
    For I = LB+1 To UBound(A)
       aTempName = A(I,1) : aTempValue = A(I,2)
       For J = I-1 To LB Step -1
          A(J+1, 1) = A(J, 1) : A(J+1, 2) = A(J, 2) : If aTempValue >= A(J,2) Then Exit For 
       Next J
       A(J+1,1) = aTempName : A(J+1,2) = aTempValue
    Next I      
End Sub
```

The function that creates a list of transactions is also not very complicated.
Check the source data for consistency between the total winnings and the total losses and, if there is no error, sort the original array, carry out settlements between the first and last players in the array, repeat the required number of times:

```
Function WhoToWhom(aData As Variant) As Variant
Dim aResult As Variant 
Dim i As Long, j As Long, LB As Integer, UB As Integer 
Dim dWin As Double, dLose As Double
    LB = LBound(aData, 1)
    UB = UBound(aData,1)
    ReDim aResult(LB-1 To UB, 1 To 3)
    dWin = 0
    dLose = 0
    For i = LB To UB
        aResult(i,1) = "" : aResult(i,2) = "" : aResult(i,3) = ""
        If aData(i,2) > 0 Then dWin = dWin + aData(i,2) Else dLose = dLose + aData(i,2)
    Next i
    If Fix((dWin+dLose)*100.0) <> 0 Then
        aResult(LB-1,1) = "Win" : aResult(LB-1,2) = "Lose" : aResult(LB-1,3) = "Difference"
        aResult(LB,1) = dWin : aResult(LB,2) = dLose : aResult(LB,3) = dWin+dLose
    Else 
        aResult(LB-1,1) = "Who" : aResult(LB-1,2) = "Whom" : aResult(LB-1,3) = "Amount"
        InsertionSort(aData)
        While aData(LB,2) < 0
            j = j + 1
            aResult(j,1) = aData(LB, 1) : aResult(j,2) = aData(UB, 1)
            If aData(UB, 2) > -aData(LB, 2) Then
                aResult(j,3) = -aData(LB, 2)
                aData(UB, 2) = aData(LB, 2) + aData(UB, 2)
                aData(LB, 2) = 0
             ElseIf aData(UB, 2) < -aData(LB, 2) Then
                aResult(j,3) = aData(UB, 2)
                aData(LB, 2) = aData(LB, 2) + aData(UB, 2)
                aData(UB, 2) = 0
             Else 
                aResult(j,3) = aData(UB, 2)
                aData(LB, 2) = 0
                aData(UB, 2) = 0
            EndIf 
            InsertionSort(aData)
        Wend 
    EndIf 
    WhoToWhom = aResult
End Function
```

The function expects a list of players expanded vertically - the name in the first column, and the amount of winnings or losses in the second. Therefore, to pass your example to a function, you should use the [**TRANSPOSE() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=SC_HID_FUNC_MTRANS#bm_id3154982)

`{=WHOTOWHOM(TRANSPOSE(A1:H2))}`

*Since this is an [**array function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=SC_HID_FUNC_MTRANS), be sure to complete typing this with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter***

[image: Example of result]

*It is possible that I made a mistake in my reasoning and there is a way to further minimize the number of transactions. If so, please correct me*

Comment: For some reason person E neither gives nor receives money in your example. Also person H receives too much. -- I am uncertain where the error comes from at the moment

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The reason is simple - the screenshot was taken before the last error in the code was corrected :-) I updated the script code after posting the answer, but the image remained unfixed. Now fixed. Thanks for your vigilance!

Comment: @JohnSUN your method is a good idea, but would not always produce optimal solution especially when is a direct match in payment. If you try out -777, -555, 555, 444, 333 your method requires 4 steps, but directly matching -555 and 555 first only requires 3 steps. [an image of result](https://imagebin.ca/v/7nalv1IOIYnv)

Comment: @H3coder Yes, you're right - I was considering the possibility of pre-processing the list, offsetting for matching amounts. This can really reduce the number of transactions (the same case about which I wrote "Ideally, both of these players will be excluded from further transactions"). This preprocessing will not greatly lengthen the script code, but for some data sets it will give better results. If you have code ready for this, post it - I'll happily vote for this idea to be implemented.

Comment: I don't have the updated code. Just to note that every loop should try to find exact match first before selecting the max for payment. I am not 100% sure even this method would provide optimal solution every time, but it is pretty good solution already.